# String printed out over multiple lines

Tags: java, string

I am not very good at java so that's why some things might not make sense at all. I was just simply using code from bits I found online which I know is wrong.

My current issue is that it simply prints a blank code; I am not sure how to get it to print it like so:

Input:

> APPLE

Output:

> A
>   AP
>   APP
>   APPL
>   APPLE

Current Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordGrow
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        //take your word input
        //enter word as a parameter in WordGrow()
        System.out.println("Please enter the word to *GROW*");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String theword = scan.next();
        System.out.println(makeTree(theword, theword.length()));
    }

    public static String makeTree(String word, int len)
    {
        int count = 0;
        //start with the first letter and print
        //and add another letter each time the loop runs
        if (word.length() > 0)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < word.length();i++)
            {
                return word.substring(0, i++);
            }
        }
        return (word.charAt(1) + makeTree(word, len));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a ***must*** to use recursion for your current problem?

Comment: You have no terminating condition. At what point will the recursion stop? Try examining this and you will have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take Java out of it.  Let's take this back to pen and paper.

First, look at the pattern you're printing out.  How would you print out just one letter of that string?  How would you print out two?

Let's start with that approach.  Let's try to print out one letter in that string.

```
public void printStringChain(String word) {
    System.out.println(word.substring(0, 1));
}
```

What about two letters?

```
public void printStringChain(String word) {
    System.out.println(word.substring(0, 2));
}
```

What about **`word.length()`** letters?

```
public void printStringChain(String word) {
    System.out.println(word.substring(0, word.length()));
}
```

The main thing I'm trying to get you to see is that there's a pattern here.  In order to accomplish this, you likely need to go from zero to the length of your string in order to print out each line on its own.

Here's a start.  I leave figuring out the nuance and barriers inside of the `substring` as an exercise for the reader.

```
public void printStringChain(String word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        // the question mark relates to i, but in what way?
        System.out.println(word.substring(0, (?)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If recursion is not compulsory, you could simply iterate through the given String:

```
String str = "APPLE";
for(int x=0; x<str.length(); x++){
    System.out.println(str.substring(0, x+1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
A
AP
APP
APPL
APPLE
```

Answer (score 0):

One cannot return multiple times, at the first moment the result is passed on to the caller.

For String there is a buffering class for efficiency, the StringBuilder.

Including the empty string that would  be:

```
public static String makeTree(String word) {
    StringBuiilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++){
        sb.append(word.substring(0, i));
        sb.append("\r\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

It uses the Windows end-of-line characters CR+LF aka `\r\n`.
You can make that platform independent, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

WITH RECURSION

```
public static String makeTree(String word)
{
    if (word.length() <= 1){
        return word;
    }
    return makeTree(word.subSequence(0, word.length()-1).toString()) + System.lineSeparator() + word;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.